# Monetdb - CPU Threads Utilization

Tags: cpu, monetdb

I have recently installed monetdb "OCT 2014-SP1" release on my Oracle Enterprise 6 Linux server.

Server configuration -

8 CPU Cores
64 GB RAM

I have loaded a data set with 70 columns having 15 Millions Rows.

I have started mserver5 as below --

```
mserver5 --debug=10 --set gdk_nr_threads=8 --dbpath=/data/monetdb/testdb  --set mapi_open=true --set mapi_port=54321  --set merovingian_uri=mapi:monetdb://localhost:54321/testdb --set mapi_usock=/data/monetdb/testdb/.mapi.sock --set monet_vault_key=/data/monetdb/testdb/.vaultkey  --set sql_optimizer=default_pipe  --set max_clients=64
```

Now I have ran a query as below --

```
select product_type,COUNT(DISTINCT sales_document),sum(ord_qty)  FROM bookings where ord_entry_date between '2014-04-01' and  '2014-10-01'  group by product_type;
```

This query took around 90 Secs .. 
So I started tomograph and checked plotted graph ... which shows the parallelism usage as 39.9 % only and its utilizing only 1 thread with maximum time went in the step - group.subgroupdone almost 98%.

My Question is that even I have started the server with gdk_nr_threads=8 , then why it is just using single thread.

More info --

```
mserver5 --version
```

MonetDB 5 server v11.19.7 "Oct2014-SP1" (64-bit, 64-bit oids)
Copyright (c) 1993-July 2008 CWI
Copyright (c) August 2008-2014 MonetDB B.V., all rights reserved
Visit http://www.monetdb.org/ for further information

Found 63.0GiB available memory, 8 available cpu cores

Libraries:

libpcre: 7.8 2008-09-05 (compiled with 7.8)

openssl: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013 (compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013)

libxml2: 2.7.6 (compiled with 2.7.6)

Compiled by: root@localhost (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

Compilation: gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2

Linking    : /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64

Any pointers ??

Comment: What happens to the parallelism if you remove the `DISTINCT`? If it makes a large difference, I would suggest rewriting the query into using two nested `GROUP BY` statements.

Answer (score 0):

The parallelism used depend on blocking operators in the plan itself.